# Function pointer to specific memory

Tags: function, memory, pointers, embedded

I'd like to ask for an advice. I am working with small embedded uP.

I'd like to assign my various functions to myfunctions struct. How to do that correctly?
Then I want to place this myfunctions (struct of function pointers) to specific memory address (e.g. 0x1000). Whats is the best procedure to achieve this?

```
typedef void (*fptr)(void);

typedef struct FCN_IMAGE
{
    fptr fcn1;
    fptr fcn2;
    fptr fcn3;
} FUNC_T;

FUNC_T myfunctions;
```

Actually it should be sort of jump table.

---

Secondly I want to read this function pointers from within other program - directly from specified address location (e.g. 0x1000).

It means the first code should assign the struct of function pointers to specific memory location and other independent code should read this table from specific memory. Interconnection between those two programs should be

```
#define FCN_BASE_ADDRESS (0x1000)
```

Any ideas what is the best way to achieve it?

P.S. This will run on embedded processor - not PC.

Comment: I think that would be a function of your linker.

Comment: partially you are right but it should be achievable to place function pointer to specific memory location, so the linker is not involved.

Comment: Example, I am not sure if it is correct:

Comment: unsigned int volatile * fcn_base = (unsigned short *) FCN_BASE_ADDRESS 
*fcn_base = ;

Comment: FUNC_T * myfunctions;
*port = myfunctions->fcn1;

Comment: Listen to the other commenters - placing data at certain locations is a function of your linker (possibly with compiler assistance in the form of #pragmas & whatnot.)  If the desired "thing" is already at the right address (e.g. memory-mapped HW registers) you don't need to play with the linker, you can just use pointers & casting.  But in your situation, you want to place a structure at a certain address.  Note that if this table of function pointers is to be placed in ROM/flash, declare it as "const" & initialize it where defined.

Comment: Also as others have commented, this is toolset & platform specific.  We need more details... GCC?  IAR?  Code Composer Studio?  AVR?  MSP430?  etc.

Answer (score 3):

Locating objects at specific locations is usually most easily performed by the use of compiler specific extension; there is no standard method defined by the language.  It may also be possible to locate a global object at a specific location by modifying the linker script, but that will be specific to your particular tool-chain

What compiler/tool-chain are you using?  Refer to its documentation.

Comment: I am using Freescale CodeWarrior tool, it seems to me there is only way by linker itself. So still studying it...

Comment: @Pepe: "Codewarior" is the name Freescale use for the development tools (IDE) for all their architectures, it tells me nothing about which compiler you are using.  I am not convinced that you are right however, look in the documentation for "[Global Variable Address Modifier (@address)](http://www.freescale.com/infocenter/Codewarrior/index.jsp?topic=/com.freescale.doc.mcu.hcs08_compiler/080_ANSI-C_Frontend.Global_Variable_Address_Modifier_%28address%29.html)" for example.

Comment: @Pepe, Clifford has answered your question.  I use Freescale Codewarrior, and the `typename varname @address` format is the way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will help you:

```
// assign my various functions to myfunctions struct
myfunctions.fcn1 = &YourFunction1;
myfunctions.fcn2 = &YourFunction2;
myfunctions.fcn3 = &YourFunction3;

// assign the struct of function pointers to specific memory location
memcpy((void*)FCN_BASE_ADDRESS, &myfunctions, sizeof(myfunctions));

// read this table from specific memory
memcpy(&myfunctions, (void*)FCN_BASE_ADDRESS, sizeof(myfunctions));
```

This is based on my guess on what you actually want to do.

Comment: I just give a try. Code compiles as suggested but does not work and no results. At specific address there is no myfunctions. Maybe memcpy does not work on this (just guessing because of function pointer)  ...

Comment: @Pepe: A memcpy is a memcpy;  if this did not work for you then you misunderstood or misapplied the solution. This will work, so long as `FCN_BASE_ADDRESS` is *not* ROM. There is however a simpler way; if `FCN_BASE_ADDRESS` is of type 'FUNC_T*` then the functions can be accessed directly via `FCN_BASE_ADDRESS->fcn1()` for example without the second memcpy().

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to solve it in a portable manner:

```
typedef void (*fptr)(void);

#define FCN_BASE_ADDRESS ((volatile fptr*)0x1000)

/* Make myfunctions an array, not a struct. 
   Structs can have padding and aren't portable.
   It doesn't look like you need a struct in this case.
*/
fptr myfunctions [N] =
{    
  fptr fcn1;
  fptr fcn2;
  fptr fcn3;
};

memcpy(&FCN_BASE_ADDRESS, myfunctions, sizeof(myfunctions));
```

Though if you are using Codewarrior, you could probably use a #pragma to allocate them where you want them. Here is an example assuming they are stored in read/write RAM and a 32-bit address bus.

```
// .prm file
SECTIONS
  MEM_FCN_BASE_ADDRESS = READ_WRITE 0x2000 TO 0x200C; 
END

PLACEMENT
  FCN_BASE_ADDRESS INTO MEM_FCN_BASE_ADDRESS;
END

// .c file
#pragma DATA_SEG FCN_BASE_ADDRESS
fptr myfunctions[N] = ...;
#pragma DATA_SEG DEFAULT
```

If they should be stored in ROM/flash, for example a vector table, then it must be done differently with READ_ONLY sections, #pragma CONST_SEG and `const fptr`. (Note that the const keyword in C behaves in irrational ways when combined with typedef:ed pointers. In this case I believe it would give a constant pointer to a non-constant function and thus it should end up in NVM as desired.)